# How to resolve UnsatisfiedLinkError faced using Java 6 program with Oracle XE?

Tags: java, oracle

I am facing below exception while running a program compiled in `Java 6` on `Windows 2008 64 bit` machine with `oracle database 11g express` edition.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3535)
```

I checked there is no 64 bit version of Oracle 11g XE.

Can you please let me know resolution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Above error is related with the compatibility of the `OCI driver version` with your Windows version.
Check if your OCI driver is compatible with a `32 bit` architecture or else is for a 64 bit (and hence the error).

Comment: How to resolve this? Oracle XE doesn't provide 64 bit version.

Comment: I even pointed my application to remote Oracle 11g but the error remains the same